# Does Euclid's demonstration that there are only five Platonic solids need to assume convexity?

Tags: convex-geometry, platonic-solids

At the end of the Elements Book XIII Euclid gives a demonstration that there are only five regular solids, i.e. 'no other figure, besides the said five figures, can be constructed by equilateral and equiangular figures equal to one another' e.g. [here](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookXIII/bookXIII.html).  The demonstration given of this is essentially that any vertex comprised of a number of equal polygons can only be formed by 3, 4 or 5 triangles or 3 squares or 3 pentagons, the reason being that any more of any of these leads to a total angle at the vertex of 360° or more.

It's been pointed out that Euclid also needs the condition of convexity.  This was probably assumed by Euclid, not least because much of the previous discussion in Book XIII was about inscribing solids in spheres.  The essence of my question is that if we don't assume this then the argument appears potentially to fail, i.e. we can easily have more than 5 triangles meeting at a vertex if it can be nonconvex, e.g. as at one of the inner vertices of a solid similar to the small stellated dodecahedron

[image: Stell dodec]

(from Wikipedia) but composed of 60 equilateral triangular faces rather than 60 isosceles triangle (not thinking of it as twelve intersecting pentagrams either).

The standard way to then show that there are only five Platonic solids is using Euler's formula $V-E+F=2$ applied to a polyhedron comprising $n$ $m$-gons, say, and showing that the only cases that work with the formula are those corresponding to the Platonic solids.

I note that without convexity then there are some other possible solids, e.g. the icosahedron with one vertex pushed in such as

[image: dented icosa]

(taken from Richeson's book 'Euler's Gem').  In a sense this is just a varied icosahedron, however, and loses the regularity that we probably want from any Platonic solid so I don't think anyone would call it a 'sixth' Platonic solid.

As above with the small stellated dodecahedron, I'm not thinking of cases where faces 'intersect' such as the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra, thinking of these as better described by a set of smaller polygons, and also note that in such solids we don't have the same number of smaller polygons meeting at each vertex so they aren't candidates for a sixth Platonic solid.  I'm also not thinking of cases where there are holes in the solid, i.e. genus not equal to 2, or where a cube might be stuck into the middle of a face etc.

To phrase one definite question then: is there a quick, knock down argument as to why a set of nonconvex vertices formed from more than 6 equilateral triangles, or more than 4 squares or pentagons, as described above, could not form a regular solid, meaning a solid with the same number of the same regular polygons meeting at each vertex?

Of course, it doesn't 'feel' as though this would be possible, and we can justify this with Euler's formula, but Euler's formula was not known to Euclid / requires algebraic manipulation not known at that time - I'm wondering if there is a justification of convexity rather than just assuming it.

Any ideas very welcome (or requests for clarification of what I mean, of course).

Comment: On the general vagaries found in definitions of "regular polyhedron" (and "polyhedron" and even "polygon"), see works by Branko Grünbaum. In particular, ["Are your polyhedra the same as my polyhedra?" (PDF link via washington.edu)](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~grunbaum/Your%20polyhedra-my%20polyhedra.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks - that illustrates well how there is no common definition of regular polyhedron as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are demanding that faces do not intersect, then the idea of angular deficit offers your proof.

Count the polygonal angles around each vertex of some convex polyhedron and see how much they fall short of 360 deg. For example the cube has 3 x 90 deg corners so is 90 deg short.

Then count the vertices and multiply that by the corner's deficit. For the cube this is 8 x 90 deg = 720 deg or 2 full turns. This is the polyhedron's angular deficit.

It is the same value for all convex polyhedra. In fact it is the same for all polyhedra which have a simple sphere-like surface, such as your dimpled icosahedron (we say they are topological spheres), regardless of any valleys, dimples, etc. and is directly related to the Euler sum V - E + F = 2.

Any skew regular vertex has an angular sum of 360 deg or more, i.e. an angular excess of 0 or more. You cannot obtain an angular deficit using only skew regular vertices. Hence you cannot obtain the necessary Euler value for your solid.

Comment: You say "A non-convex vertex has an angular sum greater than 360 deg": this is false. Consider the icosahedron with one vertex pushed in, as described in the original post.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that bit.

Comment: Why should a non-convex regular vertex have a large angle sum? Again, consider the center of the "dimple" in the icosahedron with one vertex pushed in.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect You aren't the ghost of Branko Grünbaum, are you? He used to be adept at picking up on these woopsies. Have I got it right this time?

Comment: Haha! Afraid not, just a person who's spent too long having my cute geometry arguments fall apart to this sort of thing to let my guard down anymore. (Well, except for all the times they still fail...)

Comment: I think your current answer rules out things like the Kepler-Poinsot solids, but doesn't show that the dimpled icosahedron fails? (Of course, it does fail, because some of the vertices have inconsistent dihedral angles, but you need some way of showing that these inconsistencies arise.)

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect It seems trite that an all-dimpled surface cannot exist. Multiple edges must in practice be ridges, so a figure with a dimple cannot be regular. Do you think that level of rigour is really necessary?

Comment: Maybe not? I agree it seems rather intuitive. I think you might be able to just show it with the observation that any point on the convex hull is not a dimple, and so by vertex transitivity none of them are.

Comment: Many thanks for the discussion.  I think you're quite right that the notion of angular deficit can show why we can't have a polyhedron with five squares meeting at each vertex, say (i.e. clearly a non-convex vertex, though not a dimple either?)  Such a vertex has a negative angular deficit and so no set of these could ever form a polyhedron which was a topological sphere, i.e. total angular deficit of 720 deg.

Comment: On the other hand, the notion of angular deficit is closely related to Euler's formula, and I'm trying to work out if it's possible to prove that there are only five Platonic solids only using the mathematics available to Euclid, without assuming that the polyhedron is convex, something which seems to be assumed by Euclid, but not stated explicitly in his definitions.

Comment: If we define a 'regular polyhedron' to be one where the same number of regular polygons meet at each vertex, as is sometimes seen, i.e. not ruling out non-convex vertices, then we need either angular deficit or Euler's formula to show there are only five main types of these (i.e. counting the convex and 'pushed-in' icosahedra as the same 'type', i.e. five equilateral triangles meeting at vertex). Does that seem right?

Comment: BTW - is there are more mathematical name for the 'pushed-in' icosahedron?!  Maybe 'non-convex', but then can we distinguish how many vertices are pushed in?

Comment: @John1970 By definition the Platonic solids are the convex ones. The non-convex regular solids are not Platonic. You need to be clearer about what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @John1970 People sometimes invent fun names for figures that interest them. Mathematically, both icosahedra are deltahedra (composed of regular triangles) and they are isomorphs (identical incidence structures) of each other. And you are right, you can push more than one vertex in, especially if you let the surface self-intersect.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Well, as Blue's link above shows, the definitions of solids has varied more than one might expect and I don't think we can point to 'one' definition of Platonic solids.  We all 'know' what we mean by the term of course, and that they are the ones which are convex rather than the 'pushed in' ones, but I've seen definitions where this isn't explicit, including most importantly Euclid's at the end of Book XIII, although the context makes it clear he is assuming it - this assumption being the main point of my question.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect There seem to me to be two questions - the slightly less interesting one regards the 'pushed in' solids (we could disallow by saying that by 'regular' we mean each vertex has the same dihedral angle).  The other is whether there's a simple intuitive reason why you cannot create a solid where the same number of regular polygons meet at each vertex which isn't one of the five known Platonic solids (nor one of the 'pushed in' ones).  This can be shown using Euclid's formula, or as you rightly say, using angular deficits, but is there an argument using only Euclid's mathematics?

Comment: @John1970 Plato and Euclid knew what they meant by a solid, and that is the only definition relevant to the question. But Euclid's treatment was flawed, so lawyering over the details helps nobody. Books have been written on the subject (e.g. Coxeter on *regular polytopes* and Grunbaum on *convex polytopes*) and I have no intention of writing another one in an SE comment. I can add the comment I made about dimples to my answer, if you like?

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Thank you. As far as I can see, Coxeter assume convexity in his discussion of Platonic solids so I'm not sure how this helps the current question (please correct me if I'm wrong).  I think that Grunbaum's discussion is at a higher level of abstraction than needed here.  Discussion of the flaws in Euclid's definition and their implication is exactly the question I'm interested in - I don't see it as lawyering so maybe best if we leave things here.  Thank you for your comments though.

Comment: To answer your last question, some vertices are neither convex nor dimples, so I'm not sure that your dimples comment is definitive (again, let me know if I'm wrong / have misunderstood).

Answer (score 0):

As per Guy's post, Descartes's observation that the total angular deficit of solids which are homeomorphic to a sphere is 720 deg justifies it not being possible to form such a solid where more than five equilateral triangles meet at each vertex (or more than three squares or pentagons) even though such vertices are possible in polyhedra.  To justify the total angular deficit sum being 720 deg needs Euler's formula, or similar reasoning, and so would not have been know to Euclid.  An assumption of convexity therefore seems to be needed for Euclid's argument for only five Platonic solids at the end of Book XIII of the Elements to work.

Comment: Many thanks - I agree with all you say.  I voted up Guy's post as giving the answer for this reason.  Thank you for adding your confirming of this too.